# How to adjust this query of research?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to adjust this query to do the search (like) in another column and another table.

See:

```
$query2 = "
select distinct(lances.codigo)
     , datacompra
     , horacompra
     , cupom 
  from lances
     , ".$tabelaCad." 
 where lances.idcliente = ".$tabelaCad.".id 
   and lances.datapgto = '0000-00-00' 
   and lances.horapgto = '00:00:00' 
   and (".$tabelaCad.".nome like '%".$cliente."%' or ".$tabelaCad.".usuario like '%".$cliente."%') 
 group 
    by lances.codigo 
 order 
    by lances.datacompra desc
     , lances.horacompra desc
    ";
```

He currently searches only on: `".$tabelaCad.".nome and ".$tabelaCad.".usuario.`

The variable `$tabelaCad` is the name of a table called `cadastro`, and the variable `cliente` is the one that receives the search POST.

I need her to look too in the column `codigo` from the table `lances` and in a new table called `registro` in the columns `reg1` e `reg2`.

What would the query look like in this case? I have tried several ways and it does not work.

I am working with MySQL 5.7, still...

Comment: What PHP Framework are you useing?

Comment: None, is a system made in pure php.

Comment: Ok I will take a look over it ;)

Comment: So If I am right you try to research in two tables right and are you using PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: In fact it will search in three tables..

Comment: It's not MySQLi, I'm using an old version (5.7).

Comment: MySQLi is the scripting in PHP xD or are you using a old PHP version aswell?

Comment: Yes, I am using an old version of PHP that does not support MySQLi.

Comment: What is the foreign key from registro to the other tables? So the query is finished to 80% xD

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I don't think there is a foreign key in the tables, it has only primary key with id name.

Comment: you should probably add a row which is reference that references one of the other tables.

Comment: I really do not know how to do this procedure, analyzing by phpmyadmin does not appear anything related.

Comment: Do you have Discord? So I we can talk there an I probably can help you there faster xD

Comment: I don't have it, I don't even know this platform lol.. Can we start a chat here?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: My reputation here doesn't allow chat, nor did I know it. So complicated :/ hahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197891/discussion-between-ryffle-and-zecaluis).

Comment: This query isn't something to 'adjust'. It's something to chuck in the bin and start over. If you trust that I'm right? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

After a long discussion we found the last relation between the tables.

It is `registro.reg1` to `lances.codigo`.

So the best way to solve the problem is to work with the inncer join.

You save unnecessary typing and can address the tables with aliases which is much more comfortable for writing procedures.

Here is my finished solution:

```
<?php
$query2 = "
select
    distinct lc.codigo as codigo,
    lc.datacompra as datacompra,
    lc.horacompra as horacompra,
    lc.cupom as cupom
from `lances` as lc
inner join `".$tabelaCad."` as ca on lc.idcliente = ca.id
inner join `registr` as ri on lc.codigo = ri.reg1
where lc.idcliente = ca.id
    and lc.datapgto = '0000-00-00'
    and lc.horapgto = '00:00:00'
    and (ca.nome like '%".$cliente."%' or ca.usuario like '%".$cliente."%')
group
    by lc.codigo
order
    by lc.datacompra desc, lc.horacompra desc
";
?>
```

I put them in the selection because I do not know exactly what you intend to xD

Comment: Distinct is not a function, and your result is indeterminate

Comment: No. It's gibberish.